# Get a list of Roles as a List<string> as result in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to just get a list of roles in RoleManager as a list of strings and I am using Postman to test my API.

Here's my code:

```
 public Task<List<string>> GetRoles()
    {
        List<string> roles = _roleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        return roles;
    }
```

But it keeps giving  me this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>'
```

Can someone help me out here; what do I do to convert the type, either of the response of TResult?

Comment: Is there any reason it needs to be a `Task<List<string>>`????

Comment: @JamesS I am quite new to ASP.NET Core and please correct me if I am wrong but I use Task here to return a result in an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Yes but to do so you also need to include `async` in the action declaration.

Comment: That's right! I've added that. Thank you very much @JamesS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make method async that way

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetRoles()
    {
        List<string> roles = await _roleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToListAsync();

        return roles;
    }
```

Or you can just return List instead of Task

```
public List<string> GetRoles()
    {
        List<string> roles = _roleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        return roles;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Mansi, you can try use IEnumerable<string> instead of list, maybe it'll help

Comment: I used the first method and it worked well, thank you for your help.